# obdsim: invalid option -- 'b'

Tags: bluetooth, ubuntu-14.04, obd-ii

When I run

```
user:~$ obdsim -b
```

I get

```
obdsim: invalid option -- 'b'
```

I've already done this:

```
sudo rfcomm bind 0 14:30:C6:50:12:16 1
sudo sdptool add SP
```

When I run

```
user:~$ obdsim -h
Usage: obdsim [params]
   [-g|--generator=<name of generator>
       [-s|--seed=<generator-seed>]
       [-d|--customdelay=<ecu delay(ms)>]
     ]
   [-q|--logfile=<logfilename to write to>]
   [-V|--elm-version=<pretend to be this on ATZ>]
   [-D|--elm-device=<pretend to be this on AT@1>]
   [-L|--list-protocols]
   [-p|--protocol=<OBDII protocol>]
   [-o|--launch-logger]
   [-c|--launch-screen] ["EXIT" or C-a,k to exit]
   [-t|--tty-device=<real /dev/ entry to open>]
   [-e|--genhelp=<name of generator>]
   [-l|--list-generators]
   [-n|--benchmark=<seconds>]
   [-v|--version] [-h|--help]
The generators built into this sim:
 "Random"
 "Cycle" (default)
 "Logger"
 "dlopen"
 "Socket"
 "gui_fltk"
 "Error"
```

So it seems that `-b` is not there however it's [here](http://icculus.org/obdgpslogger/manpages/render/obdsim.txt). So how am I suppose to connect to bluetooth?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Original OBDSim developer here.

That's typical of not having bluetooth compiled in. The pertinent part of CMakeLists.txt is thus:

```
SET(OBD_SIM_DISABLE_BLUEZ false CACHE BOOL "Disable bluetooth support in obdsim")
IF(NOT OBD_SIM_DISABLE_BLUEZ)
    CHECK_SYMBOL_EXISTS(BTPROTO_RFCOMM
        bluetooth/bluetooth.h
            HAVE_BLUETOOTH)
    IF(HAVE_BLUETOOTH)
        MESSAGE(STATUS "Enabling bluetooth obdsim port")
        ADD_DEFINITIONS(-DHAVE_BLUETOOTH)
    ENDIF(HAVE_BLUETOOTH)
ENDIF(NOT OBD_SIM_DISABLE_BLUEZ)
```

So... unless you explicitly disabled bluetooth when you built OBDSim, it simply means you need to include your distribution's bluetooth-devel package.

[Note that after installing, you will need to rerun cmake, having obliterated the cache. I usually just rm -rf build and start again]

Comment: Where can we add this code?

I mean I can't find this code in the file you mentioned. I am on latest edition i.e. 587